# Invalid result when multiplying negative Duration value by a negative integer

Tags: datetime, java-8, duration

```
Duration.ofSeconds(-4, 333333333).multipliedBy(-2)
```

It returns `PT7.333333334S`, I expected that the result is `PT8.666666666S`

It seems to be desired since there are test cases for it:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/test/java/time/tck/java/time/TCKDuration.java#l2151

I don't see where in the code this part is happening:

```java
public Duration multipliedBy(long multiplicand) {
    if (multiplicand == 0) {
        return ZERO;
    }
    if (multiplicand == 1) {
        return this;
    }
    return create(toSeconds().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(multiplicand)));
 }

private static Duration create(BigDecimal seconds) {
    BigInteger nanos = seconds.movePointRight(9).toBigIntegerExact();
    BigInteger[] divRem = nanos.divideAndRemainder(BI_NANOS_PER_SECOND);
    if (divRem[0].bitLength() > 63) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("Exceeds capacity of Duration: " + nanos);
    }
    return ofSeconds(divRem[0].longValue(), divRem[1].intValue());
}

private BigDecimal toSeconds() {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(seconds).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(nanos, 9));
}
```

Could you explain what/why is it happening?

Comment: Feel free to reedit or rollback if you disagree with edits. I just thought that it'll be more readable with descriptive title and code in the body than the otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument is an adjustment and not a fractional part.

`Duration.ofSeconds(-4, 333333333)` is not `-4.333333333 s`.
Instead it should be read as `-4 s + 333333333 ns` which is the same as `-3.666666667 s`.

To get the `8.666666666 s` as the result you would need to use
`Duration.ofSeconds(-4, -333333333).multipliedBy(2)`.

---

It happens in the `toSeconds` method which calculates the sum of the second and nanosecond values:

```
private BigDecimal toSeconds() {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(seconds).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(nanos, 9));
}
```

Comment: okay, got it, but can you explain where in the code this is happening? I updated my question for more information.